# When should I use total differentials and when should I use implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus

When should I use total differentials and when should I use implicit differentiation?

An example of an equation where I'm unsure if to use total differentials or implicit differentiation is $f(x, y) = x^2y$

**Using total differentials**

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dy = 2xydx+x^2dy$, solving for $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-2y}{x}$

**Using implicit differentiation:**

$(2x \frac{dy}{dx})(y)+x^2$, solving for $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x}{y}$

I'm unsure when to use each method and they both yield different results.

Answer (score 0):

If $f_{x_{j}}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}$ then
\begin{eqnarray}
df &=& f_{x}dx+f_{y}dy \\
   &=& 2xy dx+x^{2}dy
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Yes, I understood that section (and have updated the question to clarify), though I was more concerned about when should to use either method, i.e. when to use implict and when to use total differentials.